# Does Prism (CAL) provide any way to bind a command to for example a MouseClick event?

Tags: wpf, events, prism, command

I recently looked into Prism (aka the Composite Application Library for WPF) and really like the way I can structure my apps with it.

However there is one downside that I just couldn't resolve. Is it possible to bind a command (from a ViewModel for instance) to an Event (for example: RightMouseButtonDown) via Prism?

This would be a key requirement to the application I am trying to build and it would be a shame if I couldn't use Prism just because of this lacking feature.

Best regards,
crischu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not part of Prism, you can use the [AttachedBehaviours](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) from Marlon Grech.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't part of Prism, but you can define input handlers at the window level in WPF with the following code:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding MouseAction="RightClick" Command="RightClickCommand"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

It will then trigger the RightClickCommand defined in its current DataContext (the ViewModel for the window) whenever the RightMouse is clicked within the window and *not* captured by any other control in the logical tree - the event bubbles up from the control directly under the mouse.

Comment: problem with this is you cant use binding on your Command or CommandParameter